# JPA Foregin Key in Entity

Tags: java, jpa

I have tables

```
table 1- label_look-up (id, en_label, ar_label)
table 2- page_content id, label_look-up_id,image_path)
```

I use the Java Persistence API and want to defined the Entity Class, and need to defined the
(`label_look-up_id`) as foreign key , without load the label_look-up object and when i need to label.

I will fetch `en_label` or `ar_label` only(not all fields) in separate query, so what is the best practice to do that.

SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `LABEL_LOOKUPS` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `AR_LABEL` VARCHAR(3000) ,
  `EN_LABEL` VARCHAR(3000) ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `PAGE_CONTENT` (
  `ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LABEL_LOOKUPS_ID` INT NOT NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  FOREIGN KEY (`LABEL_LOOKUPS_ID`) REFERENCES LABEL_LOOKUPS (`ID`)
)
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code, both the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statements and the Java code for the entity classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a foreign key as a numeric data type. For example:

```
private Long labelId;
```

As for not loading all labels at once -I would reconsider. It's not a big deal for JPA to fetch one or two additional columns you would not use (assuming you're not loading thousands of columns).

It's more of a problem the number of queries you make to the DB.

Comment: but in this case, there is no relationship between the primary key and the foreign key, true?

Comment: you can enforce the relationship on the database level instead. That's not a big problem

Comment: thanks on your reply, i know that's not big problem, but i'm looking for the best practice.